# Asp.net mvc identity, user logs out very quickly after login

Tags: asp.net-mvc, identity

I'm using Asp.net Identity membership. I've set ExpireTimeSpan to 45 minutes :

```
  app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
  {
       AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
       LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login"),  
       ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(45),
```

But sometimes the user is logged out in less than ten minutes. It happens especially if the user is in Role Admin. I've an Admin controller where the

```
[Authorize(Roles="Admin")]
```

filter is used but it's still logging out very quickly.

Comment: Make sure the cookies are not being deleted.

Comment: Maybe you confuse: real logging out and redirecting to login page(sure, if you have this redirect logic), when user, for example, don't have role admin and attempt to execute action that only dedicated to admin role users?

Comment: Nope it's logging out

Comment: Session id is not deleted

Comment: But then why it's logging out?

Comment: .AspNet.ApplicationCookie has been deleted